# How to left join same table twice by different conditions to get correct "group by" result

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

I have this query that returns account count by person

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(a.id) accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a
  ON a.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

and it works find. It returns 2 for accounts if the person have two accounts.
But I need to get also an active account count. I trying do it this way:

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(a.id) accounts, COUNT(a1.id) active_accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a
  ON a.person_id = p.id
  LEFT JOIN Account a1
  ON a1.person_id = p.id AND a1.state = '0'
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

But this query returns 4 for accounts instead of 2.
How can I fix this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query make a cartesian product, each account is join with other account

You need a single join :

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   COUNT(a.id) total_accounts,
   sum(case when a1.state = '0' then 0 else 1 end) inactive_accounts,
   sum(case when a1.state = '0' then 1 else 0 end) active_accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a
  ON a.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. I assume state = '0' for active.

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(a.id) accounts, SUM(CASE WHEN a.state = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) active_accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a
  ON a.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: I think your second `COUNT` has a problem.  It will count both the true and false condition.

Comment: Second count returns 2 in any case

Comment: You right, I forgot to change to aggregate function to `SUM`